# A Q about S.Boyd's CVX book p. 107

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-analysis

A Q about the following: (Come from S.Boyd's note)

[image]

---

Note 1: y is a r.v with log-concave pdf "p(y)".

My Qs are:

1. What is the f(x) in the proof?  It is marginal pdf or cdf or expected value?
   It seems like an expected value?

   [image]
2. Why is 'g(u)' a log-concave function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $f(x)$ is what the question says it is: the probability that $x + y \in C$.
Since $g(x+y)$ is $1$ when $x+y \in C$ and $0$ otherwise, this is indeed the expected value of $g(x+y)$.

2) $g$ is log-concave because $C$ is a convex set.   This follows easily from the definitions of log-concave function and convex set.